# Iterate multiple times over all files in a folder and select x % of the files on each run and return the uniquely selected files

Tags: python, loops, random, iteration

Suppose you have a folder with 100 files in it and want to iterate 5 times over these 100 files and return 18 **unique** files each time in a separate .csv file. What is the most pythonic(python 3.6x) way to do that? the file names saved on each run in a .csv file must be unique(different from each run).

Comment: do you really have to loop through the file names 5 times?. like u can loop through it once save all the names in a list and then randomly choose 18 filenames and save it.

Comment: No, I don't have to loop 5 times over it! that was just my first thought. I need 5 different sets of filenames from the list of files in my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
import os

def generateFiles():
    # Enumerate is optional and is intended to let you know which file
    #  you chose
    files = list(enumerate(os.listdir(yourDirectory)))
    random.shuffle(files)
    for i in range(5):
        yield files[:18]
        files = files[18:]

def getFilesLists():
    return list(generateFiles())
```

Comment: this does not work in my case! even tho the files are unique in each list but not between the lists! say I have a folder with only 4 files  in it : f1, f2, f3,f4 and I want two unqiue lists: ideally, the code should give me [f1,f2] [f3,f4] ---> no repetition inside each list which your code does but also no repetition between the lists. Still Thank you for your time!

Comment: I am not quite sure I understood your question, my code would not make repetitions between two lists, since this is a generator (the code continues to execute from the previous `yield` keyword).

Comment: True! perhaps my description of the problem is vague! let me try my best. Say you have a folder with 100 files in it: I want five lists, in each list, I want to have exactly 18 unique file names. The filenames should be unique in each list so no repetition inside each list and no repetition between the lists. So each list should have 18 unique file names in it. A better example is: I have a folder with 100 songs give me 5 lists of  18 unique songs out of these 100 songs. So each song in each list is unique and there are no two identical songs between all the 5 lists.

Comment: So, my code does solve this problem :-) You could try it yourself. I added another function that returns a list of 5 lists, so it is clearer to see they are unique

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake! this works as you have written. Thank you! Is it also possible to iterate only once over my list of files and generate the five unique list as @Lavanya V mentioned above?

Comment: I presumably iterate only once, since I read the files (using `os.listdir`) only once. The iteration is over the number of lists you want, but it can simply be converted to list comprehension - `return [files[18*i:18*(i+1)] for i in range(5)]`